# Ternary operator should not be used on a single line in Node.js. Why?

Tags: node.js, coding-style, standards

Consider the following sample codes:

**1.Sample**

```
var IsAdminUser = (User.Privileges == AdminPrivileges)
  ? 'yes'
  : 'no';
console.log(IsAdminUser);
```

**2.Sample**

```
var IsAdminUser = (User.Privileges == AdminPrivileges)?'yes': 'no';
console.log(IsAdminUser);
```

The 2nd sample I am very comfortable with & I code in that style, but it was told that its [wrong way](https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide#use-multi-line-ternary-operator) of doing without any supportive reasons.

Why is it recommended not to use a single line ternary operator in Node.js?

Can anyone put some light on the reason why it is so?

Advance Thanks for great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all coding standards, they are generally for readability and maintainability. My guess is the author finds it more readable on separate lines. The compiler / interpreter for your language will handle it all the same. As long as you / your project have a set standard and stick to it, you'll be fine. I recommend that the standards be worked on or at least reviewed by everyone on the project before casting them in stone. I think that if you're breaking it up on separate lines like that, you may as well define an if/else conditional block and use that.

Be wary of coding standards rules that do not have a justification.

Personally, I do not like the ternary operator as it feels unnatural to me and I always have to read the line a few times to understand what it's doing. I find separate if/else blocks easier for me to read. Personal preference of course.

Answer (score 5):

It is in fact wrong to put the `?` on a new line; even though it doesn’t hurt in practice.

The reason is a JS feature called “[Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion)”. When a `var` statement ends with a newline (without a trailing comma, which would indicate that more declarations are to follow), your JS interpreter *should* automatically insert a semicolon.

This semicolon would have the effect that `IsAdminUser` is assigned a boolean value (namely the result of `User.Privileges == AdminPrivileges`). After that, a new (invalid) expression would start with the question mark of what you think is a ternary operator.

As mentioned, most JS interpreters are smart enough to recognize that you have a newline where you shouldn’t have one, and implicitely fix your ternary operator. And, when minifying your script, the newline is removed anyway.

So, no problem in practice, but you’re relying on an implicit fix of common JS engines. It’s better to write the ternary operator like this:

```
var foo = bar ? "yes" : "no";
```

Or, for larger expressions:

```
var foo = bar ?
    "The operation was successful" : "The operation has failed.";
```

Or even:

```
var foo = bar ?
    "Congratulations, the operation was a total success!" :
    "Oh, no! The operation has horribly failed!";
```

Comment: Semicolon insertion does not work like that. It does not _produce_ invalid expressions, rather when it encounters am invalid expression it tries to fix it by inserting semicolons according to _well defined_ rules.

Comment: @Odalrick: Do you have a source to support your claim?

Comment: @Ixg http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion

Answer (score 3):

I completely disagree with the person who made this recommendation. The ternary operator is a standard feature of all 'C' style languages (C,C++,Java,C#,Javascript etc.), and most developers who code in these languages are completely comfortable with the single line version.

The first version just looks weird to me. If I was maintaining code and saw this, I would correct it back to a single line.

If you want verbose, use if-else. If you want neat and compact use a ternary.

My guess is the person who made this recommendation simply wasn't very familiar with the operator, so found it confusing.

Comment: I agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's easier on the eye and easier to read. It's much easier to see what your first snippet is doing at a glance - I don't even have to read to the end of a line. I can simply look at one spot and immediately know what values `IsAdminUser` will have for what conditions. Much the same reason as why you wouldn't write an entire if/else block on one line.

Remember that these are *style conventions* and are not necessarily backed up by objective (or technical) reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for having ? and : on separate lines is so that it's easier to figure out what changed if your source control has a line-by-line comparison.

If you've just changed the stuff between the ? and : and everything is on a single line, the entire line can be marked as changed (based on your comparison tool).